# probability of two sums of random discrete numbers to be equal

Tags: probability

Suppose I throw a dice $n$ times, and sum the results in a variable $A$. 
Then I repeat and call the second sum $B$.

What is the probability that $A = B$? I assume the answer depends on the number of possible values ($6$ in this case) so let's call that number $v$.

I realize that this is equal to 
$$
\sum_{i=1..v} (P(A=i) \cdot P(B=i))
$$
but I do not know how to compute $P(A=i)$ and $P(B=i)$.

For the continues case, the Irvin-Hall distribution gives us an answer (the distribution of a sum of random variables), but what do we do in the discrete case ?

Comment: Possibly useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2304799/probabilies-of-rolling-n-dice-to-add-up-to-a-specific-sum

Comment: Not sure if by “compute” you mean analytically or numerically. In general, quite tricky. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225797/distribution-of-the-sum-of-a-multinomial-distribution)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably difficult to work out exactly, but it can be done approximately (for sufficient large $n$).

Let $k$ be the number of faces on your die. The variance of $A$ and of $B$ is $n \frac{k^2-1}{12}$, since each is a sum of $n$ independent versions of a [discrete uniform  random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution). Let $D = A - B$, then
$$
E(D) = 0, \, var(D) = n \frac{k^2-1}{6} \, .
$$ 
By the Central Limit Theorem, for sufficiently large $n$, $Z = \sqrt{\frac{6}{n(k^2-1)}} D$ is approximately standard normal. Then
$$
P(D = 0) = P(|D| \le \frac{1}{2}) = P(|Z| \le \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{6}{n(k^2-1)}}
\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{6}{n(k^2-1)}} = \boxed{\, \sqrt{\frac{3}{\pi n(k^2 - 1)}} \, } \, 
$$
This goes to zero quite slowly, which seems to be related to the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).